# What are differences/perks of the different Ballistic Vests in Payday 2

Tags: payday-2

I know the light ballistic vest makes you move a little vaster compared to the others but I want to know what exactly the differences between them all. I'm leaning towards the normal vest because it's equal between the two but depending on my playstyle (e.g. Stealth or Guns Blazing) which one would suit which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
             | Lightweight | Normal | Heavy  |
-------------|-------------|--------|--------|
Armor        |      30     |   40   |   50   |
Concealement |      26     |   23   |   21   |
Speed        |      36     |   35   |   33   |
Dodge        |     -20     |  -25   |  -30   |
Steadiness   |      11     |   12   |   13   |
Stamina      |      20     |   19   |    8   |
```

The numbers speak for themselves ; you plan to hide in the shadows, go for the Lightweight, you want to unleash a deadly storm of bullets, choose the Heavy instead.

If you want protection, however, you will appreciate the higher tier armors more.

Note : The Lightweight is, alongside the Suit, the *only* armor working with the [Grinder](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Perk_Decks#Grinder) Perk Deck.

Comment: So if I don't want to be stealth or be a tank should I just stick to the suits and not waste my time with it until higher tiers?

Comment: For stealth, always use the suit. For loud, it depends on your build, but in my experience most people always use the heaviest one available (unless running a dodge build, in which case you use the suit).

Comment: basically the middle ground armours suck because they dont provide the protection of the ICTV nor the agility or dodge of the suits or LBV. sucks a bit...